# django - how to replace repeated code in form validation

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

In my django forms.py file, I am trying to replace two occurrences of repeated validation code. Each attempt I make to have only one occurrence of each, does not seem to work.

I cannot figure out how to write the code so that I have only one occurrence of each of the repeated code in the validation. It should be possible, but I cannot understand how to achieve this.

I am hoping that someone can help me out as this has me confused.

Here is my validation code:

```
def clean(self):
    cd_cdf = super(CertificationDetailsForm, self).clean()

    # Must check the most specific cases first, then the general cases.
    if 'certification_type' in cd_cdf and cd_cdf['certification_type'] == '':
        self._errors['certification_type'] = self.error_class([_("This field is required.")])

    elif 'certification_type' in cd_cdf and cd_cdf['certification_type'] == display_types.ENTER_MY_OWN_TYPE_DESCRIPTION:
        if 'certification_type_description' in cd_cdf and len(cd_cdf['certification_type_description'].strip()) == 0:
            self._errors['certification_type_description'] = self.error_class([_("This field is required.")])

        # repeated code occurrence #1.1.
        if 'certification_title' in cd_cdf and len(cd_cdf['certification_title'].strip()) == 0:
            self._errors['certification_title'] = self.error_class([_("This field is required.")])

        # repeated code occurrence #2.1.
        if 'certification_date' in cd_cdf and cd_cdf['certification_date'] is not None:
            if cd_cdf['certification_date'] > date.today():
                self._errors['certification_date'] = self.error_class([_("Date must not be greater than today.")])

    elif 'certification_type' in cd_cdf and cd_cdf['certification_type'] != display_types.ENTER_MY_OWN_DETAILS:
        # repeated code occurrence #1.2.
        if 'certification_title' in cd_cdf and len(cd_cdf['certification_title'].strip()) == 0:
            self._errors['certification_title'] = self.error_class([_("This field is required.")])

        # repeated code occurrence #2.2.
        if 'certification_date' in cd_cdf and cd_cdf['certification_date'] is not None:
            if cd_cdf['certification_date'] > date.today():
                self._errors['certification_date'] = self.error_class([_("Date must not be greater than today.")])

    elif 'certification_type' in cd_cdf and cd_cdf['certification_type'] == display_types.ENTER_MY_OWN_DETAILS:
        if 'certification_description' in cd_cdf and len(cd_cdf['certification_description'].strip()) == 0:
            self._errors['certification_description'] = self.error_class([_("This field is required.")])
        #  remove the entered value and/or assign a default value, when the certification type only requires minimum data.

        if 'certification_type_description' in cd_cdf and len(cd_cdf['certification_type_description'].strip()) > 0:
            cd_cdf['certification_type_description'] = None

        if 'certification_title' in cd_cdf and len(cd_cdf['certification_title'].strip()) > 0:
            cd_cdf['certification_title'] = None

        if 'certification_institution' in cd_cdf and len(cd_cdf['certification_institution'].strip()) > 0:
            cd_cdf['certification_institution'] = None

        if 'certification_date' in cd_cdf and cd_cdf['certification_date'] is not None:
            cd_cdf['certification_date'] = None

    return cd_cdf
```

Here is the types code, just in case:

```
CERTIFICATE = 1
CERTIFICATE_LEVEL_I = 2
CERTIFICATE_LEVEL_II = 3
CERTIFICATE_LEVEL_III = 4
CERTIFICATE_LEVEL_IV = 5
STANDARD_CERTIFICATE = 6
INTERMEDIATE_CERTIFICATE = 7
ADVANCED_CERTIFICATE = 8
ACADEMIC_CERTIFICATE = 9
PROFESSIONAL_CERTIFICATE = 10
OTHER_CERTIFICATE = 11
ENTER_MY_OWN_TYPE_DESCRIPTION = 7777  # 7777 triggers a hidden text field to be displayed.
ENTER_MY_OWN_DETAILS = 9999

CERTIFICATION_TYPES = (
    (CERTIFICATE, _('Certificate')),
    (CERTIFICATE_LEVEL_I, _('Certificate Level I')),
    (CERTIFICATE_LEVEL_II, _('Certificate Level II')),
    (CERTIFICATE_LEVEL_III, _('Certificate Level III')),
    (CERTIFICATE_LEVEL_IV, _('Certificate Level IV')),
    (STANDARD_CERTIFICATE, _('Standard Certificate')),
    (INTERMEDIATE_CERTIFICATE, _('Intermediate Certificate')),
    (ADVANCED_CERTIFICATE, _('Advanced Certificate')),
    (ACADEMIC_CERTIFICATE, _('Academic Certificate')),
    (PROFESSIONAL_CERTIFICATE, _('Professional Certificate')),
    (OTHER_CERTIFICATE, _('Other Certificate')),
    (ENTER_MY_OWN_TYPE_DESCRIPTION, _('Enter my own Type Description')),
    (ENTER_MY_OWN_DETAILS, _('Enter my own details'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
def clean(self):
    cd_cdf = super(CertificationDetailsForm, self).clean()

    ctype = 'certification_type'
    ctypedesc = 'certification_type_description'
    ctitle = 'certification_title'
    cdate = 'certification_date'
    cdesc = 'certification_description'
    cinst = 'certification_institution'

    # Must check the most specific cases first, then the general cases.
    if ctype in cd_cdf:
        if cd_cdf[ctype] == '':
            self._errors[ctype] = self.error_class([_("This field is required.")])

        elif (cd_cdf[ctype] == display_types.ENTER_MY_OWN_TYPE_DESCRIPTION) or (cd_cdf[ctype] != display_types.ENTER_MY_OWN_DETAILS):
            if cd_cdf[ctype] == display_types.ENTER_MY_OWN_TYPE_DESCRIPTION:
                if ctypedesc in cd_cdf and len(cd_cdf[ctypedesc].strip()) == 0:
                    self._errors[ctypedesc] = self.error_class([_("This field is required.")])
            else:
                if ctitle in cd_cdf and len(cd_cdf[ctitle].strip()) == 0:
                    self._errors[ctitle] = self.error_class([_("This field is required.")])

                if cdate in cd_cdf and cd_cdf[cdate] is not None:
                    if cd_cdf[cdate] > date.today():
                        self._errors[cdate] = self.error_class([_("Date must not be greater than today.")])

        elif cd_cdf[ctype] == display_types.ENTER_MY_OWN_DETAILS:
            if cdesc in cd_cdf and len(cd_cdf[cdesc].strip()) == 0:
                self._errors[cdesc] = self.error_class([_("This field is required.")])
            #  remove the entered value and/or assign a default value, when the certification type only requires minimum data.

            forcheck = [ctypedesc, ctitle, cinst]
            for i in forcheck:
                if i in cd_cdf and len(cd_cdf[i].strip()) > 0:
                    cd_cdf[i] = None

            if cdate in cd_cdf and cd_cdf[cdate] is not None:
                cd_cdf[cdate] = None

    return cd_cdf
```

I replaced your frequently mentioned strings with self-obvious variables and joined the second and third conditions. I haven't tested this.

I agree with the first answer, it's ineligant and unpythonic, but I have no idea what all these conditions are about so I can't shorten the code any further.